# Align li containing svg, with other li containing font-awesome icons

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

FontAwesome is missing one Icon and as such I have to fall back to using an svg.

```html
<ul class="icons other">
    <li><a>
        <svg width="50" height="50">...</svg>
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="fab fa-soundcloud"></a></li>
    <li><a class="fab fa-spotify"></a></li>
</ul>
```

with the following styling (scss),

```
.icons {
    >li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;

        >a, svg {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            box-shadow: 0 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56);
        }

        .fab {
            background-color: black;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Cains/owarL5p1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `li` are inline items, make them vertically middle, and make `a` as block elements because height width won't work on inline elements.

```
.icons {
    >li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align:middle; /*** added this ***/

        >a, svg {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            box-shadow: 0 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56);
            display:block;    /*** added this ***/
        }
        
        .fab {
            background-color: black;
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dk8eLcfm/

---

Edit: after @TemaniAfif comment.

Though above solution also worked, but I agree with Temani afif's point that, we can give `vertical-align:top` to `svg`, as it's also an inline element and can remove display block from `a`.

```
.icons {
    >li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align:middle;

        >a, svg {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            box-shadow: 0 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56);
         
            svg{
              vertical-align:top;
            }
        }
        
        
        
        .fab {
            background-color: black;
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2bcamf86/1/

Comment: Wow, I wasnt aware vertical align was a thing! Thanks!

Comment: Now you know the secret ;P

Comment: the display:block is not needed because font-awesome is already adding inline-block

Comment: @TemaniAfif It was needed on anchor tag, which does not have `.fa` class

Comment: not needed for that one because it contains a real SVG having a size 50x50 (you can omit it and the result will be the same). So not needed for the first because it contain an SVG and not needed for the other because they have inline-block from the `fa`

Comment: but the SVG inside may need  `vertical-align:top` too to avoid the extra white space below

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `display: flex` to `ul.icons`

`ul.icons.other { display: flex; }`